# generating density plot where domain and incidence given

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot `geom_histogram` and `geom_density` both expect an **x** aesthetic, where each will look at the incidence of a variable across its domain.

I have a function that outputs **both** the domain and incidences for some distribution (i.e. does not present the events in a countable form, rather in an already-counted form).

The actual value set is coming from an external library, so will set up an example here.  I would like to plot this distribution:

```
data <- data.frame(depth=seq(0,20), incidence=seq(0,20)^1.5)
ggplot() + geom_density (aes(x=depth, y=incidence), data=data, fill='lightblue')
```

The above does not work.  Of course I can use x=depth or x=incidence on its own and generate a plot, however, neither would be correct, as the x variable is considered to be the variable we are counting events over.

It occurs to me that could take the data frame and generate rows for each depth, where the # of rows corresponds to the incidence #.  This becomes more complicated with fractional incidence, but could scale.

Question: is there a way to generate a density plot in ggplot given incidence rather than events?  If not, I guess could use something like:

```
c (apply (data, 1, function(r) rep(r[1], r[2])), recursive=TRUE)
```

to generate a discrete approximation of events.  A direct way within ggplot would be better.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why can't you plot with `geom_line()`?

Comment: I suppose if supplemented with smoothing (otherwise would be very jagged) and with an area fill.  I guess could construct rectangles for the area fill, though not sure about how to do the smoothing directly in ggplot?

Comment: Why don't you post data that resembles your real data. ggplot does smoothing for you without a problem.

Comment: I am going to close this as it seems that geom_density and geom_histogram are oriented towards doing their own binning and smoothing.  I will have to preprocess outside of ggplot

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is

```
qplot(depth, data = data, weight = incidence, geom = "histogram", binwidth = 1)
```

If you need to do this with `geom_histogram` then it is the slightly longer

```
ggplot(data , aes(x = depth)) + 
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(weight = incidence))
```

producing

[image]